# Targeting window.location.pathname in Next.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, next.js

Do you know how to target window.location.pathname in NEXT.JS ?

I have this code and next.js shows me nice red err

```
const path = window.location.pathname
     console.log(path) // here I am getting pathname
```

Than

```
         {  
            path === '/product' ? <p className='mt-2'>Products</p> :
            path === '/contact' ? <p className='mt-2'>Contact</p> :
            path === '/cart' ? <p className='mt-2'>Cart</p> :
            <p className='mt-2'>Home</p>
          }
```

Comment: you can't directly access the window object on the server-side. To get the current pathname in a Next.js component, you can use the `useRouter` hook from the next/router package

Comment: Like this:- `import { useRouter } from 'next/router';`

```const router = useRouter();
  const path = router.pathname;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `window.location.pathname` in Next.js because the `window` object is not available on the `server-side` in Next.js. The server-side rendering of Next.js doesn't have access to the window object, which is a client-side object, because it doesn't run in a browser environment.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

And then use it inside your component.

```js
const router = useRouter();
const path = router.pathname;

  return (
    path === '/product' ? (
      <p className='mt-2'>Products</p>
    ) : path === '/contact' ? (
      <p className='mt-2'>Contact</p>
    ) : path === '/cart' ? (
      <p className='mt-2'>Cart</p>
    ) : (
      <p className='mt-2'>Home</p>
    )
     //...
  );
```

Comment: mmm, getting the same on client side.